# removing certain common text from the column names in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

how can we remove anything before 'dot' in the column names of a sql table:

Suppose, SQL table has following names:

```
xyz1_sdef1.my_header_name1
xyz2_sdef2.my_header_name2
xyz3_sdef3.my_header_name3
.
.
.
.
```

But what I want, when I should run:

```
Select * from myTable;
```

I should get :

```
my_header_name1   my_header_name2   my_header_name3   my_header_name4
    123213213       .                 .                  .
    456546546       .                 .                  .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you strip a character out of a column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983417/how-do-you-strip-a-character-out-of-a-column-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List the columns, give them aliases

```
select xyz1_sdef1.my_header_name1 as Header1 -- this is a column alias
from MyTable
```

Courtesy of Lakshmi:

MySQL ALIASES can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables. COLUMN ALIASES are used to make column headings in your result set easier to read. Use something like this:

```
SELECT column1 as COL1, 
       column2 AS COL2, 
       ...... 
FROM Table_1;
```

Comment: what if there are many columns. and I want to remove all "text_before_dot"

Comment: List all the columns, apply an alias to each.

Comment: @Madhu Sareen   MySQL ALIASES can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.

COLUMN ALIASES are used to make column headings in your result set easier to read. Use something like this:
`SELECT column1 as COL1, column2 AS COL2, ......
FROM Table_1;`

Comment: et al. Thanks so much. I was thinking if there are 50s of cols then it will be painful. I wonder if ti could be done through some automated function or so.